# Micorsoft Graph API Responsibilites Update

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am attempting to update the responsibilities field on a user account through the Graph API.

I am attempting to do this using the following request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn>

{
    "responsibilities":[
        "ApprovalLimit:0"
    ]
}
```

When i make this request, I get the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
        "message": "Invalid attribute update\r\nParameter name: attributeUpdates",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1be313f3-880b-47de-858d-1bea74951715",
            "date": "2017-03-06T09:29:21"
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to update the schools collection, which is also a String collection, this works without issue.

This is the same with both `beta` and `v1.0` and also with the `/me` endpoint rather than `/users/<upn>`.

Is this a bug within the API?

Any ideas about how to set this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also able to reproduce this issue too. Based on the error message, it seems this attribute is not support update at current version of Microsoft Graph.

If you want to this attribute is update-able, I suggest that you submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: Thanks for that. I have posted the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18538816-enable-update-of-users-responsibilties-from-the-mi) for anybody who would like to vote for it. However, leaving the question open in case anybody has a workaround or knows of somewhere else it can be temporarily updated.

Comment: There's a bug in the underlying service which we are fixing.  I'll post back when it's fixed - hopefully it'll be soon.